# How do I force Interactive Brokers to connect to their US based servers?

Tags: interactive-brokers, ibpy, ib-insync

My interactive brokers gateway runs in the cloud in the US. I am a european citizen, so IBKR seems to always connect me to their EU servers, even though my trading system runs in the USA and I am trading US equities.

People say that if you use IBKR you should not worry about speed anyways, but accumulating two times the distance over the atlantic for every api call is just unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You write to IB customer support requesting the change of the main data server to New York or Chicago. Warning: some IB support people don't know know anything about this.